# GPIO stuck in High Mode

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2, led

I'm new to this whole RP world, and I'm trying to learn it.

I've been trying to follow this [post](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/27968772-turning-on-an-led-with-your-raspberry-pis-gpio-pins), and connected my Pi this image below

**Connection between Pi and Adafruit T-Cobbler Plus**

[image]

**Wiring**

[image]

Without having to run any code, my LED kept lighting up.

---

I created a file trying to turn it off.

**ledOff.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
print "LED off"
GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
```

I ran it

`sudo python  ledOff.py`

I got the message to print  "LED off" on my CLI , but that about it. LED is still on.

I'm not sure why my GPIO is stuck in a high mode.

---

I've tried rebooting my pi

`sudo shutdown -r now` still seeing the same result. :(

---

**Details**

**GPIO Version** : 0.6.0a3

**PI OS** : Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7v7-aufs

---

Did I do anything that I'm not suppose to do here ?

---

**Update**

I've tried 
update my GPIO to 0.6.1

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
```

---

Try running again, I got the message to print again, but the light is still ON

```
pi@raspberrypi$ sudo python ledOff.py 
LED off
```

---

I'm running out of ideas now, any suggestions will be much appreciated !

Comment: Could you check that the ribbon cable between the Pi and the cobbler is inserted correctly?  Normally the white stripe would indicate pin 1.  Perhaps it needs to be twisted.  If you have a meter check that 5V is 5V at the cobbler, not 3V3.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean pin 1 ?

Comment: Need a twisted ? Should I physically twist it ? or just maybe reverse it to see the different ?

Comment: I don't have meter yet, I need to get one. You mentioned 5V and 3V3, but I'm sure if I am currently using it right now. I allowed the power to flow directly from **pin#17**.

Comment: If the cable is connected wrong the labels on the left side of the cobbler will be for the pins on the right side of the cobbler.  Have a look at the site you bought the cobbler from or at its instructions and see if they say how to connect the cobbler to the Pi.

Comment: I believed I connected it correctly. Is there anything else, that you suspect that might happen here ? Do you think I need to update my GPIO ?

Comment: I don't think there is any need to update the software,  Could you add another photo showing both ends of the ribbon cable as connected.

Comment: I updated the image on the post.

Comment: It's best to have both photos if you can.  You'll need to wait for someone with that cobbler to comment as to whether it's connected properly or not.

Comment: Sure, I'll the old on one in. But my script look correct right ?

Comment: What do you think about my python code ? I hope I didn't do anything wrong there.

Comment: The code looks fine.  It might be better to switch the LED on and off several times with a delay between each for testing purposes.

Comment: How do I switch it on/off ? If u don't mind I ask.

Comment: Add import time at the start.  Use GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW) time.sleep(1) GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH) time.sleep(1) GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW) time.sleep(1) etc. (separate lines per statement).

Comment: Have you tried replacing `GPIO.LOW` with `False`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cable is connected wrong. The end on the cobbler is Ok but the end on the RPi needs to be reversed so that the white stripe is next to the RPi's onboard led's. I had this same issue many months ago.

From the manufacturer (Adafruit's) [website](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2028):

[image: Image of T-shaped GPIO adapter, plugged into a electronics breadboard with a ribbon cable bearing a white-stripe on one side connecting that to a RPi B+ or 2B model - the cable is connected to the latter the opposite way around to the one in the OP's first picture.]

Comment: I have added in a picture to show as per @pxgator says, you have the cable connected incorrectly on the RPi end.  You may have been lucky and not broken anything on the RPi or anything semiconductor-*ish* on the breadboard but that will be a fortunate escape - the corner-most pin on one end of the 40 pin connector is +5V whereas the diagonally opposite one is Ground - swapping them over is ***not good for anything made out of silicon*** - otherwise you may have got your question an "*rip*" tag 8-)!

Comment: @pxgator : You're a life saver man !